# How can I use .Equals("string") in delegate if condition?

Tags: c#, delegates

I am using `BackgroundWorker`, there is an if condition inside that `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` but its giving cross thread operation error.

I tried the  below code but it say object reference not set to instance of an object. Can any one tell me how can I use `Equals` method inside delegate?

```
  ((bool)(scrapeType.Invoke(new Action(() => { scrapeType.Text.Equals("Scrape URLS"); }))))
```

`scrapeType` is a `TextBox`.

Comment: It's the fact that you're accessing `scrapeType.Text` from a thread which isn't the UI thread that's causing the exception -- nothing to do with `Equals("string")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of the `Dispatcher` type. Here's an example:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> if(txtBox.Text.Equals("abc")) doThis(); else doThat();)
```

You didn't mention what framework you are using, so I assumed it is WPF.